# How to stop auto play RYPP youtube video

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I am using the RYPP youtube video player for video but its always play automatically when it is loaded at first time.I tried to find out the problem but i could not succeed.

If anyone can help me to fix it Please. here i added some of codes. for more code to view please see the [github](https://github.com/carloscabo/responsive-youtube-player-with-playlist/blob/master/README.md) of this video.

This is the code of RYPP.js

```
 // Api key
  this.api_key = api_key;

  // Default options
  this.options = {
    update_title_desc: false,
    autoplay: false,
    autonext: false,
    loop: false,
    mute: false,
     // Logs debug messages in console
    debug: false     // Default
  };
```

Here the Html links : http://news365.bdtask.com/Demo/DemoNews365/home-style-one.html

Answer (score 0):

On line 50 onwards of [**RYPP.js**](https://github.com/carloscabo/responsive-youtube-player-with-playlist/blob/master/js/RYPP.js) :

```
// Default options
      this.options = {
        update_title_desc: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autonext: true,
        loop: true,
        mute: false,
        debug: false
      };
```

Untested : Maybe if you set that `autoplay: true` to become `autoplay: false` it might work.

---

**Edit** :

According to the [**ReadMe**](https://github.com/carloscabo/responsive-youtube-player-with-playlist/blob/master/README.md#settings--options) about settings :

> You have several **parameters** you can pass **on RYPP start** to control some
>   basic behaviours...
>
> ```
> $('#RYPP-custom-player').rypp( '{{YOUR_API_KEY_HERE}}', {
>
>   // Player starts automatically on first video
>   autoplay: true, // Default
>
>   // Player loads next video automatically
>   autonext: true, // Default
>
> });
> ```

Comment: Not Working.Please give me another solution.

Comment: My bad you have to set autoplay: false during the loading of Player, not just in JS code. [**Update your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44082978/edit) to show how you initialize the RYPP player within your page. Show us a basic html code whose job is to just load & start the player. Then maybe it can be modified into a working solution.

Comment: It is solved.Please use this code for solving the issues : http://news365.bdtask.com/Demo/DemoNews365/js/RYPP.js

Comment: It is solved.Please use this code for solving the issues.Just copy this and paste at your RYPP.js Code :http://news365.bdtask.com/Demo/DemoNews365/js/RYPP.js